# Position coordinates of an element related to viewport (not relative) via JS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am building a vueJs web-app and I need the position of an element inside my web-app according to the viewport (not to the relative parent element). I wonder if there is a function/property doing this.

**.offsetLeft** is not what I need, because the element is inside of parent-elements with *position: relative*.

Please check out my pen: https://codepen.io/mister-hansen/pen/aGdWMp
(With an example what different position: relative makes.)

**HTML**

```
 <div id="app">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box__in" ref="my_box_a">
      What is my position?
      <br> offsetLeft: <strong>{{posBoxA}}</strong>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="box box--relative">
    <div class="box__in" ref="my_box_b">
      What is my position in relative box?
      <br>
      offsetLeft: <strong>{{posBoxB}}?!</strong>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**JS** - VueJs

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {

      posBoxA: 0,
      posBoxB: 0,
      }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.calcPosOfBox()
  },
  methods: {
    calcPosOfBox () {
      this.posBoxA = this.$refs['my_box_a'].offsetLeft

      this.posBoxB = this.$refs['my_box_b'].offsetLeft

    }
  }
})
```

**SCSS**

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  padding: 10vh 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.box {
  margin: 0 auto 10vh;
  padding: 10vh 50px;
  background: lightgrey;

  &--relative {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
  }

  &__in {
    padding: 1rem;
    background: lightgreen;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).  The `x` and `y` it returns are relative to the top-level viewport.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. See solved issue in other pen: https://codepen.io/mister-hansen/pen/PeZQZJ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).  The `x` and `y` returns are relative to the top-level viewport.

Emphasis mine:

> The returned value is a `DOMRect` object which is the union of the
>   rectangles returned by `getClientRects()` for the element, i.e., the CSS
>   border-boxes associated with the element. The result is the smallest
>   rectangle which contains the entire element, with read-only `left`, `top`,
>   `right`, `bottom`, `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` properties describing the
>   overall border-box in pixels. **Properties other than `width` and `height`
>   are relative to the top-left of the viewport**.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {

      posBoxA: 0,
      posBoxB: 0,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.calcPosOfBox()
  },
  methods: {
    calcPosOfBox() {
      const boxABB = this.$refs["my_box_a"].getBoundingClientRect();
      const boxBBB = this.$refs["my_box_b"].getBoundingClientRect();
      this.posBoxA = boxABB.x;
      this.posBoxB = boxBBB.x;

    }
  }
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  padding: 10vh 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.box {
  margin: 0 auto 10vh;
  padding: 10vh 50px;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.box--relative {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.box__in {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box__in" ref="my_box_a">
      What is my position?
      <br> offsetLeft: <strong>{{posBoxA}}</strong>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="box box--relative">
    <div class="box__in" ref="my_box_b">
      What is my position in relative box?
      <br> offsetLeft: <strong>{{posBoxB}}?!</strong>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Here is my solved issue as a pen: https://codepen.io/mister-hansen/pen/PeZQZJ